# Can Samsung Galaxy s9 upgrade its OS from 10 to 11?

Tags: android, mobile

I have a basic s9 but need to upgrade the OS to 11. My phone regularly does system updates (did one yesterday) but the Android Version says it is 10. Google says to go under settings > System > System Update but I don't have a Systems option in settings.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your phone, go to Settings > tap Software update and then download & install.
If you can't, then the software update isn't available in your region/for your model yet.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I checked that setting and it shows my phones update to date. I'm in the UK so like you said it might be available in my region or my phone might be too old.